# Random output in assembly program. Using system calls for OSX

Tags: macos, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I've searched around and I haven't found anything.

The code is as follows:

```
  hello_world     db      "Hello World!",10
  .hellolen       equ     $ - hello_world

  get_input       db      "Enter a number: ",10
  .getlen         equ     $ - get_input

  input           times  10 db 0
  .len            equ     $ - input


section .text
global start

; Arguments go in the registers 
;RDI, RSI, RDX, R10, R8, and R9, in order. 
;System call number goes into RAX.

start:
call printHello
call askInput
call takeInput
call printInput
call exit
ret

printHello:
mov rax, 0x2000004
mov rdi, 1
mov rsi, hello_world
mov rdx, hello_world.hellolen
syscall

askInput:
mov rax, 0x2000004               ; System call write = 4                
mov rdi, 1                       ; Write to standard out = 1
mov rsi, get_input               ; The address of enter string
mov rdx, get_input.getlen                      ; The size to write
syscall   

takeInput:
mov rax, 0x2000003               ; System call read = 3
mov rdi, 2                       ;
mov rsi, input                   ; buffer that we are reading to
mov rdx, input.len               ;to create buffer overflow
                                 ;we can input more than
                                 ;input.len
syscall

printInput:
mov rax, 0x2000004               ; System call write = 4                
mov rdi, 1                       ; Write to standard out = 1
mov rsi, input                   ; The address of enter string
mov rdx, input.len                      ; The size to write
syscall 

exit:
mov rax, 0x2000001      ; System call number for exit = 1
mov rdi, 0              ; Exit success = 0
syscall                 ; Invoke the kernel
```

And the output:

```
Hello World!
Enter a number:
r:                 <- weird random r:
test               <- input by me
test               <- correct value returned
```

Is there a way to view this with GDB so that I may figure out what is causing this problem? I'm not sure how to approach this from a troubleshooting perspective. Thank you!

I edited the code according to commentary and I am still getting the same odd `r:` in the output.

Comment: Your telling it to print 64 characters. sys_write keeps on writing 64 bytes which will continue off the end of your strings.

Comment: BTW, `call askInput` never runs: your labeled blocks don't `ret`, they just  fall through into the next one, in order, until you reach the exit.  So if you single-step in a debugger, you'll see that your `call` instructions are all useless and you should just remove them.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about that. I changed each procedure so that they have a `ret` .